# What can I do to prevent certain charaters being matched in regex?

Tags: regex, vba

I need help with a regex to prevent characters other than '-' and ',' from being recognised in conjunction with numbers.

I have a stream of data which consists of numbers 0 to 9 which are delimited with a comma but can never start with a 0 (could contain 10 but not 01).  Some of these delimited packets can be hyphenated.  An example of the groups of numbers are as follows:

12-34,56,78-90,12,34-45,67-8,90

I need to have the regex return groups for each comma delimited section, ie:

```
Group 1: 12-34

Group 2: 56

Group 3: 78-90

Group 4: 12

Group 5: 34-45

Group 6: 67-8

Group 7: 90
```

So far I have this pattern:

`[1-9]+\d*(?:-[1-9]+\d*)?(?=,|$)`

The problem is that if the numbers contain a spurious character other than a number, '-' or ',' the group is partially recognised:

12£34,56,78-90,12,34-45,67-8,90

Group 1: 34

How can I fix this?  I am using vba for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:^|,)([1-9]\d*(?:-[1-9]\d*)?)(?=,|$)
^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z1TtYk/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5E%7C%2C)(%5B1-9%5D%5Cd*(%3F%3A-%5B1-9%5D%5Cd*)%3F)(%3F%3D%2C%7C%24)):

[image]

The main point is the `(?:^|,)` group that matches start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a comma. Note I  removed `+` from `[1-9]` to lessen the amount of backtracking.

**Details**

- `(?:^|,)` - start of string or `,`
- `([1-9]\d*(?:-[1-9]\d*)?)` - Capturing group 1 (access it via **`match.Submatches(0)`**):

  - `[1-9]\d*` - a digit from `1` to `9`  and then any 0+ digits
  - `(?:-[1-9]\d*)?` - an optional sequence of `-`,  a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 0+ digits
- `(?=,|$)` - comma or end of string.

VBA test:

```
Sub Test()
Dim val As String, rx As New regExp
Dim ms As MatchCollection, m As Match

val = "12L34,56,78-90,12,34-45,67-8,90"
Set rx = New regExp
rx.Pattern = "(?:^|,)([1-9]\d*(?:-[1-9]\d*)?)(?=,|$)"
rx.Global = True
Set ms = rx.Execute(val)
If ms.Count() > 0 Then
 For Each m In ms
   Debug.Print m.SubMatches(0)
 Next
End If

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might be just in search of a simple expression, such as

```
^(\d+-\d+|(?:\d+\D)\d+),(\d+),(\d+-\d+|(?:\d+\D)\d+),(\d+),(\d+-\d+|(?:\d+\D)\d+),(\d+-\d+|(?:\d+\D)\d+),(\d+)$
```

to maybe fulfill your grouping requirements from 1 to 7 and you can add an optional group for those `\D` chars that you may have anywhere within your strings.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/4G5cQI/1/)